# Python Multiprocessing speed with single process

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, pool, ptvs

I've found some behavior with python multiprocessing I'm having difficulties understanding.
When using Pool, even if it is a single process, it performs much, much faster.

Why is that? Does multiprocessing somehow optimize the code?

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


fib_input = [24] * 10

def fib(n):
    if n in [0,1]:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)


def main1():
    with Pool(processes=1) as p:
        results = p.map(fib, fib_input)
    print (results)


def main2():
    results = list(map(fib, fib_input))
    print (results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main1()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    main2()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
[75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025]
--- 0.47702741622924805 seconds ---
[75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025]
--- 7.922452926635742 seconds ---
```

Comment: On my machine, I get `main2()` is faster:


    [75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025]
    --- 0.426348924637 seconds ---
    [75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025, 75025]
    --- 0.31747508049 seconds ---

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta same with me `0.23288583755493164 seconds` vs `0.1788322925567627 seconds`

Comment: Similar with me -
First: 0.4335339069366455 seconds
Second: 0.25878310203552246 seconds

Comment: GREAT guyz! That what i was counting on.
So the setup is the problem?
I'm using python 3.5.1 64x on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to comments I figured out my bad. Thanks guys!

A rookie mistake.

I was using Visual Studio PTVS. That is where the slowdown was from.
I've changed the dropdown 'build' to Release, however pressing f5 was still running debug mode, while I was convinced it was a clean run.

Running it in cmd outside did the trick. Later I figured that also ctrl-f5 starts without debugging.

Thanks for the help.